# How can I execute a set of functions on all columns in a Polars dataframe?

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to execute multiple operations on all columns on a polars dataframe using the `pl.all` function.

For the time being, I am using this code:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["hello", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 1, 1]}
)

def col_operations(column: pl.Series):
    col_stats = {
                "count_unique": column.n_unique(),
                "count_nans": column.null_count(),
                "nan_frac": column.null_count()/len(column)        
                 }
    
    return col_stats

def profile(df: pl.DataFrame):
    profiling_dict = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        profiling_dict[col] = col_operations(df[col])
    
    return pd.DataFrame(profiling_dict)

profile(df)
```

which returns what I want to see:

```
                a   b   c
count_unique    3.0 3.0 1.0
count_nans      0.0 0.0 0.0
nan_frac        0.0 0.0 0.0
```

However, for my actual use case I am working on tables that can have ~15 columns and potentially millions of rows, so I'm looking for something faster than what I came up with.

I tried to use `pl.all` as argument to `df.select`, but this raises a `DuplicateError` exception:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["hello", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 1, 1]}
)
df.select([pl.all().sum(), pl.all().mean()])
```

yields

```
DuplicateError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 4
      1 df = pl.DataFrame(
      2     {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["hello", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 1, 1]}
      3 )
----> 4 df.select([pl.all().sum(), pl.all().mean()])

File ~/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py:6503, in DataFrame.select(self, exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)
   6395 def select(
   6396     self,
   6397     exprs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr] | None = None,
   6398     *more_exprs: IntoExpr,
   6399     **named_exprs: IntoExpr,
   6400 ) -> Self:
   6401     """
   6402     Select columns from this DataFrame.
   6403 
   (...)
   6500 
   6501     """
   6502     return self._from_pydf(
-> 6503         self.lazy()
   6504         .select(exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)
   6505         .collect(no_optimization=True)
...
   1473     streaming,
   1474 )
-> 1475 return wrap_df(ldf.collect())

DuplicateError: column with name 'a' has more than one occurrences
```

Adding a suffix seems to work:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["hello", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 1, 1]}
)
df.select([pl.all().sum().suffix("_sum"), pl.all().first().suffix("_first")])
```

yields

```
a_sum   b_sum   c_sum   a_first b_first c_first
i64 str i64 i64 str i64
6   null    3   1   "hello" 1
```

This is kind of what I want to see, however I would rather have a format like that in the first example.

With Pandas, I can get this done with `.apply`:

```py
dfp = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["hello", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 1, 1]}
)

def col_operations(column: pd.Series):
    col_stats = {
                "count_unique": column.nunique(),
                "count_nans": column.isna().sum(),
                "nan_frac": column.isna().sum()/len(column)        
                 }
    
    return pd.Series(col_stats)



dfp.apply(col_operations, axis=0)

# Output
                count_unique    count_nans  nan_frac
                a   b   c
count_unique    3.0 3.0 1.0
count_nans      0.0 0.0 0.0
nan_frac        0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Is this doable in some way using Polars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you really want to expressionize your `col_operations` and `profile` methods.

Let's deconstruct `col_operations`.

```
"count_unique": column.n_unique(),
"count_nans": column.null_count(),
"nan_frac": column.null_count()/len(column)
```

We can use the [documented means to register our own Exprs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_expr_namespace.html)

**Method 1** (do everything wide then melt/split/pivot

```
@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("col_ops")
class AnyNameHereIsFine:
    def __init__(self, expr):
        self._expr = expr
    def n_unique(self):
        return self._expr.n_unique().suffix("_____count_unique")
    def null_count(self):
        return self._expr.null_count().suffix("_____count_nans")
    def nan_frac(self):
        return (self._expr.null_count()/self._expr.count()).suffix("_____nan_frac")
```

Now we can get `dir` and `getattr` to do it all.

```
df.select(getattr(pl.all().col_ops, x)() for x in dir(pl.Expr.col_ops) if x[:1]!="_")
```

Of course, you don't want the wide format....who would?

From here you've got to do melt/split/pivot

```
(
    df.select(getattr(pl.all().col_ops, stat_method)() for stat_method in dir(pl.Expr.col_ops) if stat_method[:1]!="_") 
    .melt()
    .with_columns(varsplit=pl.col('variable').str.split("_____"))
    .with_columns(c1=pl.col('varsplit').arr.first(),
                  c2=pl.col('varsplit').arr.last())
    .pivot('value', 'c2', 'c1')
)
```

**Method 2** (struct/unnest/concat)

```
@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("col_ops")
class AnyNameHereIsFine:
    def __init__(self, expr):
        self._expr = expr
    def n_unique(self):
        return pl.struct([pl.lit("count_unique").alias("stat"), self._expr.n_unique().cast(pl.Float64())])
    def null_count(self):
        return pl.struct([pl.lit("count_nans").alias("stat"), self._expr.null_count().cast(pl.Float64())])
    def nan_frac(self):
        return pl.struct([pl.lit("nan_frac").alias("stat"), (self._expr.null_count()/self._expr.count()).cast(pl.Float64())])
```

In this method, we create structs at the outset which are essentially a means of having one expression return two columns.  In the struct is one column labeling the stat and then of course the stat itself. Then we do it a row at a time and concat all those rows into a final answer like this:

```
pl.concat(
    df.select(getattr(pl.all().col_ops, stat_method)()).unnest('stat') 
        for stat_method in dir(pl.Expr.col_ops) if stat_method[:1]!="_")
```

This method might benefit from using lazy frames.  ie, instead of that, do:

```
df=df.lazy()
pl.concat(
    df.select(getattr(pl.all().col_ops, stat_method)()).unnest('stat') 
        for stat_method in dir(pl.Expr.col_ops) if stat_method[:1]!="_").collect()
```

The benefit to lazy frames comes from [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) specifically this:

> parallel

> Only relevant for LazyFrames. This determines if the concatenated lazy computations may be executed in parallel.

In the first method, we get the benefit of parallelization by virtue of doing all the stats in the same expression but then we have to do all the melting and pivoting afterwards which eats up some of those benefits. In this method we're never splitting strings, melting, or pivoting but we're doing the calc one method at a time rather than all at once which might have a penalty. By doing it with lazy frames, concat can work in parallel thereby giving that benefit back (maybe).

props to [@ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20557510/%ce%a9%ce%a0%ce%9f%ce%9a%ce%95%ce%9a%ce%a1%ce%a5%ce%9c%ce%9c%ce%95%ce%9d%ce%9f%ce%a3) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453175/use-list-comprehension-for-expression-functions)

Comment: I just tried this solution in my setting and it is about 7x faster than my original implementation (~3.5s vs 24s). This is really cool, but I really hope it can get implemented in a more concise way by the library in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I thought of another approach and edited it in. It's slightly more concise and I think should be faster as well.

Comment: I do like the second approach more. As for the performance, I was surprised to see it's slightly slower than the first solution (`3.27 s ± 173 ms` vs `3.24 s ± 210 ms`).

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** "Simpler" approach using `.concat_list` + `pl.struct`

```
col_stats = dict(
   count_unique = pl.all().n_unique(),
   count_nans   = pl.all().null_count(),
   nan_frac     = pl.all().null_count() / pl.all().len()
)

names = pl.Series(col_stats.keys())
stats = [ pl.struct(stat) for stat in col_stats.values() ]

(df
 .select(
   name = names, 
   stats = pl.concat_list(stats).flatten())
 .unnest("stats"))
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ name         ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---          ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str          ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞══════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ count_unique ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ count_nans   ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ nan_frac     ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
└──────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

---

**Original answer:**

There may be a better approach, but it is possible to reshape the suffixed version using [`.melt`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) and [`.unstack`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unstack.html#polars.DataFrame.unstack)

After the `.unstack` you're left with columns `value_0, value_1, ...`, so we build a mapping of that back to the original column names to pass to `.rename`.

```
col_stats = {
   "count_unique": pl.all().n_unique(),
   "count_nans": pl.all().null_count(),
   "nan_frac": pl.all().null_count()/pl.all().len()
}
```

```
width = len(df.columns)
columns = dict(zip([f"value_{n}" for n in range(len(df.columns))], df.columns))
names = pl.Series(col_stats.keys()).alias("name")
```

```
(df.select(stat.suffix("_" + col) for col, stat in col_stats.items()) 
   .melt()
   .select("value")
   .unstack(width, how="horizontal")
   .rename(columns)
   .select(names, pl.all())
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ name         ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---          ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str          ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞══════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ count_unique ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ count_nans   ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ nan_frac     ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
└──────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I am trying to test this solution, but it is not clear to me how you're defining `col_stats`... In my example, `col_stats` is defined as a function of the column to evaluate, and I don't see how that can be applied to this solution. Could you add that part as an edit?

Comment: It's `col_stats` from your example, just with `pl.all()` instead of `column` - I've added it in.