# How to simultaneously compute multiple summary statistics over all columns using polars lazyframe

Tags: python-polars

Say I have some data as follows:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

For each column, I want to compute the following: mean, standard deviation, minimum, and maximum.

In pandas, I could do:

```
df.agg(['mean','std','min','max'])
```

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| std | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| min | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| max | 7 | 8 | 9 |

In polars (via the lazyframe route), the "lack of index" seems to make this challenging. I can compute 1) one aggregation at a time over all columns, or 2) all aggregations over one column at a time, then collect them out and cobble them together in pandas, but I can't seem to figure out the pure "polars" way of doing this.

Let me know, thanks!

---

I was expecting something like the following to work, but I can't do agg without groupby as in pandas:

```
temp.select(pl.all().agg(['min','max','mean','std']))
```

I then tried the following, but it's trying to stack column-wise and complains about duplicate column names:

```
temp.select([
    pl.all().mean(),
    pl.all().std(),
    pl.all().min(),
    pl.all().max(),
]).collect()
```

One solution is to rename them so they can stack column-wise (then unstack in pandas afterwards based on the suffix):

```
temp.select([
    pl.all().mean().suffix('_mean'),
    pl.all().std().suffix('_std'),
    pl.all().min().suffix('_min'),
    pl.all().max().suffix('_max'),
]).collect()
```

Below is a Frankenstein/workaround solution that works but is ugly:

```
pd.concat((
    (
        temp
        .select(pl.all().mean())
    ).collect().to_pandas().T.rename(columns={0:"mean"}),
    (
        temp
        .select(pl.all().std())
    ).collect().to_pandas().T.rename(columns={0:"std"}),
    (
        temp
        .select(pl.all().min())
    ).collect().to_pandas().T.rename(columns={0:"min"}),
    (
        temp
        .select(pl.all().min())
    ).collect().to_pandas().T.rename(columns={0:"max"}),
),axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you `temp.melt().groupby()` or do you need the same shape as the pandas output?

Answer (score 4):

```py
(
   df.select(
      mean = pl.struct(pl.all().mean()),
      std  = pl.struct(pl.all().std()),
      min  = pl.struct(pl.all().min()),
      max  = pl.struct(pl.all().max()),
   )
   .melt()
   .unnest('value')
   .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ variable ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str      ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ mean     ┆ 4.0 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 6.0 │
│ std      ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0 │
│ min      ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 │
│ max      ┆ 7.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 9.0 │
└──────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`describe`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.describe.html) method that has these statistics per column. You can `filter` the rows down if you really only want these four:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 4, 7], 'b' : [2, 5, 8], 'c' : [3, 6, 9]})
df.describe(percentiles=None).filter(pl.col('describe').is_in(['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max']))
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ describe ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str      ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ mean     ┆ 4.0 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 6.0 │
│ std      ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0 │
│ min      ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 │
│ max      ┆ 7.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 9.0 │
└──────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

EDIT: I see you might want a `lazy` way to do it. But I think by definition all these methods need every value of the column to calculate, so I'm not sure there is any point to making it lazy here (and maybe why there is no LazyFrame.describe method).

Comment: Maybe, (just maybe, I don't know) in lazy save memory mode it can do each column at a time so that it doesn't need all the data in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

In borrowing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453175/use-list-comprehension-for-expression-functions) answer you can do like this:

**Method 1**

```
aggs=['mean','std','min','max']
tempsep="_____"
(
    df
        .select(getattr(pl.all(), x)().suffix(tempsep+x) for x in aggs)
        .melt()
        .with_columns(pl.col('variable').str.split(tempsep).list.to_struct())
        .unnest('variable')
        .collect()
        .pivot('value','field_1','field_0','first')
)
```

and in borrowing from [jqurious's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76560342/1818713) technique we can combine the two to get rid of the string splitting and pivot like this:

**Method 2**

```
aggs=['mean','std','min','max']
(
    df
        .select(**{agg:pl.struct(getattr(pl.all(), agg)()) for agg in aggs})
        .melt()
        .unnest('value')
        .collect()
)
```

**Method 3**

```
pl.concat([
    df.select(pl.lit(agg).alias("agg"), getattr(pl.all(), agg)().cast(pl.Float64())) 
        for agg in ['mean','std','min','max']
]).collect()
```

**Performance**

Using the following as the df to test:

```
df=pl.LazyFrame({
    x:np.random.normal(1,100,1000000)
        for x in ['a','b','c']
})
```

Then we get

| Method | avg time | ± |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.8ms | 557µs |
| 2 | 7.74ms | 316µs |
| 3 | 14.6ms | 224µs |

So we see that method 2 is the fastest. I'm not surprised method 1 is so far behind because of its string splitting and pivoting but I'm surprised method 3 is as bad as it is.

**Making it more convenient**

We can monkey patch this as a method to DataFrame and LazyFrame like this:

```
def agg(self, aggs):
    return (self.lazy()
        .select(**{agg:pl.struct(getattr(pl.all(), agg)()) for agg in aggs})
        .melt()
        .unnest('value')
        .collect())
pl.LazyFrame.agg=agg
pl.DataFrame.agg=agg
del agg
```

Having done that, now you can just do:

```
df.agg(['mean','std','min','max'])
```