How to pass aggregation functions as function argument in Polars?
How can we pass aggregation functions as argument to a custom aggregation function in Polars?
You should be able to pass a single function for all columns or a dictionary if you have different aggregations by column.
import polars as pl

# Sample DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "category": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

def agg_with_sum(df: pl.DataFrame | pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.DataFrame | pl.LazyFrame:
    return df.group_by("category").agg(pl.col("*").sum())

# Custom function to perform aggregation
def agg_with_expr(df: pl.DataFrame | pl.LazyFrame,
                  agg_expr: pl.Expr | dict[str, pl.Expr]) -> pl.DataFrame | pl.LazyFrame:
    if isinstance(agg_expr, dict):
        return df.group_by("category").agg([pl.col(col).aggexpr() for col, aggexpr in agg_expr.items()])
    return df.group_by("category").agg(pl.col("*").agg_expr())

# Trying to pass a Polars expression for sum aggregation
print(agg_with_sum(df))
# ┌──────────┬───────┐
# │ category ┆ value │
# │ ---      ┆ ---   │
# │ str      ┆ i64   │
# ╞══════════╪═══════╡
# │ A        ┆ 3     │
# │ B        ┆ 12    │
# └──────────┴───────┘

# Trying to pass a custom Polars expression
print(agg_with_expr(df, pl.sum))
# AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'agg_expr'

print(agg_with_expr(df, {'value': pl.sum}))
# AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'aggexpr'


You can use getattr() like in the answers for https://stackoverflow.com/q/76720815/ - but it's simpler to just pass the full expressions directly: {'value': pl.col('value').sum()} (or even simpler to not use a dict?)

Thank you very much jqurious. That solves the issue. You just pass a list of expressions for each column or a single expression for all columns as parameter.

You can pass it as anonymous function with expression as parameter (I simplified your example just to illustrate the point):
def agg_with_expr(df, agg_expr):
    return df.group_by("category").agg(agg_expr(pl.col("*")))

agg_with_expr(df, lambda x: x.sum())

shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ category ┆ value │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ B        ┆ 12    │
│ A        ┆ 3     │
└──────────┴───────┘

update. as @orlp mentioned in comments, in this particular case you could do it without anonymous function, with plain usage of pl.Expr.sum(), which is much more neat.
agg_with_expr(df, pl.Expr.sum)

shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ category ┆ value │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ A        ┆ 3     │
│ B        ┆ 12    │
└──────────┴───────┘


Thank you for the suggestion. Using lambda functions can slow down performance due to overhead from Python's runtime. I prefer using built-in Polars expressions for better efficiency if it's possible in this case.

lambda function is going to be evaluated before passing control to polars, so there should be no (noticeable) performance overhead.

While it's true there's no performance overhead for a lambda here, in this particular example you can just write agg_with_expr(df, pl.Expr.sum). The lambda version is more flexible though, letting you write lambda x: (x.min() + x.max())/2 for example.

True that, @orlp, I'll update my answer
